# Python: spider recursive loop

Tags: python, web-crawler

I have a simple BeautifulSoup crawler which returns server links on depth 2 or more, depending on the amount of functions added:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def spider():
    address = "http://dog.carnivore.mammal.xyz"
    pageFull = requests.get(address)
    pageText = pageFull.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pageText, "html.parser")
    for link in soup.findAll("a"):
        href = link.get("href")
        print(href)
        depth2(href)

def depth2(address):
    pageFull = requests.get(address)
    pageText = pageFull.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pageText, "html.parser")
    for name in soup.findAll("a"):
        href = name.get("href")
        print(href)
        depth3(href)

def depth3(address):
    etc...

spider()
```

This can of course be expanded further, but what i am searching for is the way to expand the spider function to make it recursively continue up on new links by itself, without new depth methods – but only as long as the new depth is still on the server, in this case *mammal.xyz.* How could such a recursive loop be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

from urllib.parse import urlparse, urljoin

MAX_DEPTH = 4

already_visited = set()


def _get_uri(base_url, href):
    if href.startswith('#'):
        print('discarding anchor {}'.format(href))
        return None

    # We use urljoin to deal with relative hrefs (e.g. <a href="../about.html">)
    # urljoin resolves them using the base_url we provide
    absolute_url = urljoin(base_url, href)

    # Here we take the hostname and we strip www because we want to consider
    # www.test.com and test.com as the same location
    base_url_host = urlparse(base_url).hostname.replace('www.', '')
    absolute_url_host = urlparse(absolute_url).hostname.replace('www.', '')

    # Skip if the href is external (outside of the starting domain)
    # Note that we just stripped www so that www.foo.com and foo.com are considered ==
    if absolute_url_host != base_url_host:
        print('Skipping {}'.format(href))
        return None

    return absolute_url


def spider(start_address):
    _crawl_page(start_address, '/', [])


def _crawl_page(start_address, uri, followed_path):
    path = followed_path[:]
    if len(path) > MAX_DEPTH:
        return

    # For better debugging, we keep track of the current recursion path by creating a list
    # of the hrefs visited by this recursion branch. Instead of using curr_deep, we can just check
    # the length of the visited list, as we append items as we visit them.
    path.append(uri)

    print('Visiting: {}, path: {}'.format(uri, path))

    # Update a set with the current href, so that we don't visit twice the same uri.
    # In practice hrefs should be normalised here to be safe, it's not trivial to deal with
    # all the possible edge cases consistently.
    already_visited.add(uri)

    pageFull = requests.get(start_address)
    pageText = pageFull.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pageText, "html.parser")

    for link in soup.findAll("a"):
        uri = _get_uri(start_address, link.get("href"))

        if uri and uri not in already_visited:
            # Recursively visit the links. 
            # Note this is a depth-first search (DFS) visit of a tree. 
            _crawl_page(start_address, uri, path)


spider("http://www.sheldonbrown.com/index.html")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, i can’t get this to run yet – if `_crawl_page(href, curr_depth + 1)` is activated with any depth, this error keeps popping up: `requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '#': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://#?`

Comment: That's probably because you need a more robust function that accepts anchor links and relative URLs, and you don't want to send a request to an anchor URI. I updated my answer.

Comment: Great! However, what is `domain` argument? It’s currently missing as a variable in the code, so it doesn’t run; if added (with same address as in `spider` call, so a second time) the code runs, but only on depth 2, as `MAX_DEPTH` switcher no longer works.

Comment: forgot one bit, I updated the answer. The domain is inferred from the start_address. I haven't really tested properly the code so sorry if there's other glitches, but you should get the idea from my example code.

Comment: A, `domain` variable under `spider` function, ok! Now it runs, however the `MAX_DEPTH` switcher still only prints on depth 2, regardless of it’s value. Also in Python 3 the `urlparse` library seems to have been changed and now imports as `urllib.parse import urlparse`.

Comment: I updated the answer. It wasn't working because I added 1 to the current depth for every visited link. Instead, we want to increment it before we loop over the links, so all the links will be at the same depth level.

Comment: Actually tried with Python3, updated with some fixes, better logging.

Comment: I’m sorry, after the last change i can no longer follow the code since it’s uncommented, while being too different from my original. I’m also still not sure if the switch actually works (and how it’s needed with the new `_get_uri` function), since there is no printout of e-mail addresses or images as was in the original. Still, i appreciate your work, and if you like, i can accept your answer – even though i’m not sure to what extent it answers the original main question of _how could such a recursive loop be accomplished?_...

Comment: Added comments to the code, hopefully it's easier for you to follow. I think my example code answer your question, which is about how to implement recursion for a web crawler.